# Handle booting failure for u boot ( Debian )

Tags: debian, boot, partition, dual-boot, u-boot

I have an embedded device with 512 Mb of ram and 4Gb internal storage. ( Consider Raspberry Pi or Beaglebone )

I have an external SD card available with 3 Partitions.

`mmcblk0` is the disk and `mmcblk0p1`, `mmcblk0p2` and `mmcblk0p3` are the 3 partitions on it.

`mmcblk0p2` and `mmcblk0p3`, each Partition has a Debian OS.

`mmcblk0p2` is used as an active partition while `mmcblk0p3` is used as backup partition.

I have seen a behaviour that u boot prefers first partition. It reads the uEnv.txt from the partition and boots accordingly.

So partition `mmcblk0p1` has a uboot configuration. (`uEnv.txt` and other files that are required for booting)

I am using `uEnv.txt` to change the boot configuration i.e. If I want to boot from `mmcblk0p3` I can give

```
mmcargs=setenv bootargs console=tty0 console=${console} ${optargs} ${cape_disable} ${cape_enable} root=/dev/mmcblk0p3 rootfstype=${mmcrootfstype} ${cmdline}
```

in the `uEnv.txt`

If `uEnv.txt` gets corrupt due to any failure or the partition is corrupt then the device won't boot from either of the partitions. (i.e. OS)

If the `uEnv.txt` or active partition is corrupted then How can I boot from another partition on reboot? It would be great if you could share some links or resources available related to this topic i.e. How can I handle the situation?

Comment: You could include a test if else statement in uboot however if the partition is corrupted or you fail to boot then you would need need out-of-band management systems to automatically reboot the device on a failed boot. However this may just end up being an endless boot cycle if the boot loader is corrupted. You will need to manually intervene at some point.

Comment: I cannot manually intervene so I was looking for some mechanism which can help me in handling such situations. For example, something which will check if it's booting into the partition and after a certain number of tries it will boot from another partition ( i.e. another os )

Comment: This would be some kind of monitoring solution most likely. Many of these come with an associated cost and overhead infrastructure that would be installed along side the embedded device. Depending on what kind of device this is depends on how it would be power cycled and how to handle how to boot. For example beaglebones support tftpboot which means you can have boot images stored on a remote server that the beaglebone can reference when booting. This is a hard question to answer and people who know the answers usually charge big bucks to provide the solution I am afraid to say.

Comment: If you edit your post to be more specific about your setup, available infrastructure, and what you have working specifically so far and what is not working then you might have an easier time getting a good response to your question.

Comment: I have edited the post with setup and available infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

If you're implementing your own OTA from scratch then yes, you'll probably want to look at how other existing OTA mechanisms handle this as typically you use some combination of flags to know if there's an update, and if you've tried the update.

Comment: I have done that But I am not able to handle the booting issues. As I am using uboot How can I handle this for uboot? Is there any mechanism available in uboot to check if the partition is not booting try to boot from another partition?

Comment: Yes and no.  There is no upstream-do-nothing-just-works mechanism in U-Boot itself to do all of this for you.  Yes, Mender and SWUpdate are two well known OTA mechanisms that use U-Boot and have solved this problem.  This is done by setting flags in the environment and then checking them with your bootcmd to see what to do next based on which conditions are true and false.  Since you're trying to do what sounds like a traditional A/B update mechanism, you should probably strongly consider using an existing project that does all of that for you.